# MongoDB: Create composite _id including the current timestamp

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In this mongodb blog post:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-2

the following code snippet is suggested:

```
    { 
        "$push": { 
            "history": {
                "type": "buy",
                "ticker": "MDB",
                "qty": 25,
                "date": ISODate("2018-11-02T11:43:10")
            } },
        "$inc": { "count": 1 },
        "$setOnInsert": { "_id": "7000000_1541184190" }
    },
    { upsert: true })
```

Specifically on the $setOnInsert line, a compound _id is used where the second part of the id is a timestamp. I want to follow this pattern where the timestamp is the current timestamp. I have been unable to determine a way to accomplish this.

Update commands include $currentDate but this command wants a field and handles the setting of the timestamp value. I cannot see a way to use $currentDate to create a compound key where only part of the key is the actual timestamp.

Another alternative is to use an aggregation pipeline in the update. In an aggregation pipeline $$CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can be used to get the current timestamp and $concat to build the compound _id. However I cannot see an equivalent to $setOnInsert when using an application pipeline in an update (with the upsert option set to true).

I can pass a creation timestamp from the javascript client making the calls to the mongodb js driver but I thought it would be safer if the timestamp was calculated by the mongo database itself.

Comment: You can use a sub-document (a composite field) as the `_id` field, with two fields: a timestamp and the other  field (instead of concatenating two fields into a single string).